# CloudWatch Logs Insights : aggregate by time range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm new with CloudWatch Logs Insights, and I cant figure out how to aggregate data by time range with 3 columns.

The log file I want to parse is json formatted :

```
{'ts': '12:01:00', 'method':'GET',  'url':'aaaa'}
{'ts': '12:02:00', 'method':'GET',  'url':'aaab'}
{'ts': '12:03:00', 'method':'POST', 'url':'aaac'}
{'ts': '12:04:00', 'method':'GET',  'url':'aaad'}
{'ts': '12:05:00', 'method':'POST', 'url':'aaae'}
{'ts': '12:06:00', 'method':'GET',  'url':'aaaf'}
{'ts': '12:07:00', 'method':'POST', 'url':'aaag'}
```

As you can see, each event line is a POST or a GET. Each event is also time stamped.

I want to use Insights to Visualize GET and POST distribution over time in a 5mn window.

I cant find the correct syntax to have such result in the Query monitor :

```
# : ts       : NbGET  : NbPOST
1 : 12:00:00 : 3      : 1
3 : 12:05:00 : 1      : 2
```

With such results, I would be able to draw a graph with the two extracted metrics 'GET' and 'POST' .

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 10):

This can be achieved by using the 'stats' function binning by the desired time period.  For your example this roughly is:

```
STATS count(method = "GET") as NbGET, count(method = "POST") as NbPOST BY BIN(5m)
```

Comment: I believe this will return the same count for all methods. The count function only checks if the field exists and doesn't evaluate the conditional. "count() (or count(*)) counts all events returned by the query, while count(fieldName) counts all records that include the specified field name." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Comment: I believe you are right - sum(method = "GET") ... should work however.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me until I read it in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html) but `BIN()` is using the `@timestamp` field.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar with the HTTP status. You could use the same logic for the method.

```
(... parse your logs and get a field method ...)
| parse method /(?<isGet>GET?)/
| parse method /(?<isPost>POST?)/
| parse method /(?<isPut>PUT?)/
| parse method /(?<isDelete>DELETE?)/
| stats count(isGet) as nbGets, count(isPost) as nbPost, count(isPut) as nbPut, count(isDelete) as nbDelete by bin(5m)
```